# Auto increment sequence number in codeigniter and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I am having a hard time figuring out that's wrong with my code... i am generating an student information system in codeigniter with auto generated student number base on the student first name, last name,  sequence number and year of registration... my problem is that when i refresh the form or close the registration and open it again the sequence number always start in 00001 it only do counting if the form is not refreshed or close but if you reopen it the count was return to 00001

[form sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fBy6.jpg)

MY JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getInitials(firstName, lastName) {
    return (firstName[0] + lastName[0]).toUpperCase()
  }

  function getYear() {
    return (new Date).getFullYear() % 100
  }

  function paddedNumber(number) {
    var result = 0;
    for(var i = 4 - number.toString().length; i > 0; i--) {
      result += "0"
    }
    return result + number
  }



  function makeStudentID(firstName, lastName, studentNumber) {
    return getInitials(firstName, lastName) + paddedNumber(studentNumber) + ("-") + getYear()
  }

  var sequenceNumber = 1;
  function gatherDataAndOutput() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstname").value
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lastname").value
    var outputElement = document.getElementById("student_no")

    outputElement.value = makeStudentID(firstName, lastName, sequenceNumber)

    sequenceNumber++
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the culprit:

```
var sequenceNumber = 1;
```

Javascript doesn't retain any state information (it could by setting a cookie that would allow some persistence as long as you use the same browser, but it's a bit overkill) and on pageload you're always initializing your code setting `sequenceNumber = 1;`

What you could easily do is first determine the latest sequence number that has already been set (`select max(sequencenumber) from table` and then pass that value to the view) and have the view initialized with that value instead of 1.

Suppose you passed the sequence number to the view as `$seq_nbr`, if your JS code is inline in the view and not being called from an external file, you could set the `sequenceNumber` value when loading the view like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(...snip...)

  var sequenceNumber = <?php echo $seq_nbr; ?>;
  function gatherDataAndOutput() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstname").value
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lastname").value
    var outputElement = document.getElementById("student_no")

    outputElement.value = makeStudentID(firstName, lastName, sequenceNumber)

    sequenceNumber++
  }
```

Comment: Sorry but i never try to use select max  can you please help me how i can code it properly

Comment: It's as simple as that... Just run a query on the database table where you store the user information for users that have already been created and find the largest sequence number already assigned: `select max(sequencenumber) from usertable` (replace sequencenumber with the actual field name where the number is stored, and usertable with the actual name of the table). Return the result from the model to the controller, pass it on to the view and you're set